# Desktop database tool with custom form and rich data display

Tags: windows, open-source, database, gui-builder, database-browser

Basically a generic CRUD application for desktop. I found [Database Tour](https://www.databasetour.net/) which displays the data pretty well, supporting url, image, boolean checkbox, etc. However it doesn't have a custom form GUI for data insertion, and it's proprietary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Kexi](https://community.kde.org/Kexi/Releases). It's open source and free as in freedom.

Comment: Thanks! This fits all my needs. I love the simplicity. Wish there are more software like these.